# how to generate graphql files in a custom directory via netflix.graphql.dgs.codegen.gradle.GenerateJavaTask

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, gradle, graphql, netflix-dgs

in my gradle file I have

```
plugins {
    ...
    id("com.netflix.dgs.codegen") version "5.5.0"
}
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation("com.netflix.graphql.dgs.codegen:graphql-dgs-codegen-gradle:5.5.0")
    implementation("com.netflix.graphql.dgs:graphql-dgs-spring-boot-starter:4.9.11")
}
 
tasks.withType<com.netflix.graphql.dgs.codegen.gradle.GenerateJavaTask> {
    schemaPaths = mutableListOf("$projectDir/src/main/resources/schema")
    generateClient = true
    packageName = "com.example.api.generated"
}
```

in above code, the package `com.netflix.graphql.dgs.codegen.gradle.GenerateJavaTask` cannot be imported and used properly. I need to store generated files in `generated` directory. what am I missing here? search package also is not helping to find it.

[image]

Comment: What does "cannot be imported and used properly" mean? What command are you running, and what output are you getting?

Comment: @aSemy intellij makes is red and `GenerateJavaTask` is not available to be called.
in `com.netflix.graphql.dgs.codegen.gradle.` suggestions are `CodegenPluginExtension` only and `GenerateJavaTask` is not there.

Comment: What happens if you run a Gradle command from the command line? Have you tried syncing IntelliJ? https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/guide/tutorials/working-with-gradle/syncing-and-reloading/

Comment: @aSemy tried `./gradlew build ` and build is successful. but yet same problem.